# Obtaining a relation between reads and writes with Pin

Tags: pintool

I'll be honest, Pin is confounding my intuition. Let's say, for the sake of argument, I have a line

```
 a = b + c
```

and I wish to then store the addresses of b and c as a's dependencies, say, in a map,

```
m[address of a].append(address of b, address of c)
```

My current understanding of this involves

```
if (INS_IsMemoryRead(ins)||INS_IsMemoryWrite(ins))
for(memOp=0;memOp<INS_MemoryOperandCount(ins);memOp++)
INS_InsertPredicatedCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR) AnalysisFunction, IARG_MEMORYOP_EA, memOp, IARG_THREAD_ID, IARG_END);
```

where AnalysisFunction would essentially take the memory address from the operation and somehow return it, or put it into a map. But I'm not entirely certain how to do that, or how to correlate the reads to writes properly.

Any help would be appreciated